# How To Change a Variable Name Depending on Another Variable?

Tags: iphone, variables, methods, int

I have a UIImageView called `platform1`, `platform2`, `platform3`, etc.  I have an `int` called `platformNumber` coming from one method (method1) into another method (method2).

Method2 (contents not useful to my question):

```
CGPoint origin = platform1.center;
CGPoint target = CGPointMake(platform1.center.x, platform1.center.y+10);
CABasicAnimation *bounce = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
bounce.duration = 0.1;
bounce.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:origin.y];
bounce.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:target.y];
bounce.repeatCount = 1;
bounce.autoreverses = YES;
[platform1.layer addAnimation:bounce forKey:@"position"];
```

How do I change it so whereever `platform1`.center.x appears, it changes to `platform[platformNumber]` depending in the `platformNumber` value passed through?

Thanks, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: using `valueForKey` if they are property of the object, or doing a switch at the beginning: `UIView*aPlateform; switch(thePlaftormNumber){case 1:aPlateform=plaform1;break;etc.}`

Answer (score 0):

The answers proposing KVC are not scalable at all; please don't do that. You can't declare a variable at runtime, so would will be stuck with however many image views you could attach a property too.

You need to build an array of your image views and iterate them. I repeat, KVC is not intended for this.

```
NSMutableArray *imageviews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//...

[imageViews addObject:platform1];
[imageViews addObject:platform2];
[imageViews addObject:platform3];
//...
```

Then iterate the array:

```
foreach (UIImageView *imgView in _imageViews) {
    CGPoint origin = imgView.center;
    CGPoint target = CGPointMake(imgView.center.x, imgView.center.y+10);
    CABasicAnimation *bounce = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
    bounce.duration = 0.1;
    bounce.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:origin.y];
    bounce.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:target.y];
    bounce.repeatCount = 1;
    bounce.autoreverses = YES;
    [imgView.layer addAnimation:bounce forKey:@"position"];
}



int index = 3;

_imageViews[index]
```

returns you platform2 in your example (array start at 0, so subtract one)

Comment: My method1 has an if statement saying, "if this happens then platformNumber = 1" or "if this happens then platformNumber = 2", and then my method2 reads platformNumber and should change method2 accordingly.  Will this still work?

Comment: The array holds all of your imageviews 'in a row'. so if (x) platformNumber =1 { UIImageView *img = _imageViews[0];}

Just remember that arrays start indexing from the 0th index, whereas we humans start at 1. so platform1 is at position 0, platform2 is at 1 etc

Comment: this should help http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsarray.html

Comment: Thanks Davbryn for your help, unfortunately I am fairly new to iOS development and programming in general (but I have learnt what an array is), and don't quite understand what is happening in your solution.  Could I move this discussion to chat, if you have some free time?  I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: In my second method, I did:

'-(void)method2:(int *)levelNo {
    
    //ARRAY
    NSMutableArray *imageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    [imageViews addObject:platform1];
    [imageViews addObject:platform2];
    [imageViews addObject:platform3];
    //ARRAY
    
    for (UIImageView *imgView in imageViews) {
        ...
    }
    
    int index = 3;
    
    imageViews[index];'

what do I do in my frist method for each 'if' condition?  Make levelNo change?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also create a function

```
-(UIImageView*)getPlatformForNumber:(int)number {
    switch(number)
    {
        case 1:
            return platform1;

        case 2:
            return platform2;

        ...
    }

    // should not come here
    return nil;
}
```

and call that function where necessary. Sometimes that solution comes in handy - but the array proposed in davbryn's solution is of course  more scalable.